# Attaching New Volume to Persistent Volume Claim (Kubernetes)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, disaster-recovery

Been working on a disaster recovery plan for my Kubernetes cluster and I am able to make snap shots of my managed disks but im not sure how to bind a recovered manager disk to an existing volumn cliam so I can re hydrate my data after a loss of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount any disk [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume#mount-disk-as-volume) as a volume in a POD to recover data. Better approach would be to use [Velero](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure/blob/master/README.md) to take k8s configuration backup. It will save the disk and PVC information and should restore the volume claims smoothly.

Additionally, have you looked at [AzureCSI](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azuredisk-csi-driver) drivers? That's the hot stuff in AKS right now. It does support Volume [snapshotting and recovery](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/azuredisk-csi-driver/tree/master/deploy/example/snapshot) from within the cluster. Best practice still would be to use [Velero for configuration](https://velero.io/blog/csi-integration/) with CSI to backup whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much where I landed as well. Looked into ASR but doesn't really work well with this construct